# Storing a single column csv file in array format in azure data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to copy a csv file having single column line by line and storing each record in an array variable using for each activity. I am trying to write the data of that variable to file but not able to do that.

How can we achieve that only by ADF ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Lookup activity and don't check `First row only` option. You will get an array and each item is object, something like this:

```
"value": [
        {
            "column_name": "value1"
        },
        {
            "column_name": "value2"
        },
        {
            "column_name": "value3"
        },
        {
            "column_name": "value4"
        },
        {
            "column_name": "value5"
        }
    ]
```

If you only want to get array like this: `["value1","value2","value3","value4","value5"]`, you can add a variable and loop `@activity('Lookup1').output.value` to append value to your variable.

Comment: Thanks Steve, I am able to form the Json data but the issue is that how to load this data in a file . I am getting this data in Append variable but unable to use this value to load in a file.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the right application of pipeline to manage data for scalability. You can use dataflow for ETL tasks like this.